# Get the header text of all collapsible header in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have used collapsible in my project. Here i want to get collapsible header value.
sample code is shown here

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true"  data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
<h3>HEADER1</h3>
</div>
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true"  data-theme="a" data-content- theme="a">
<h3>HEADER2</h3>
</div>                                                      
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true"  data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
<h3>HEADER3</h3>
</div>
```

Now i need all collapsible header should store in an array like this

```
var h3Text={"HEADER1", "HEADER2", "HEADER3"};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target the `h3`([element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)) child([child selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)) of div with attribute `data-role="collapsible"`([attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)) then use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to convert the `h3` to a text a value as given below

```
var h3Text = $('div[data-role="collapsible"] > h3').map(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text())
}).get()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eJet4/)

Note: the array syntax used is wrong, it should be `var h3Text=["HEADER1", "HEADER2", "HEADER3"];`

Comment: thank u ...its working like a charm..but some other text also coming with that, like     HEADER1 click to expand  how to remove that unwanted text?

Comment: @Raj can you edit the fiddle to recreate the problem